# Fixing conmutation for high voltage switching with power MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, switching, powermosfet

I have an issue with a charge circuit for a capacitor as load.

I want to switch approximately 400 V DC to charge a 1000 µF 600 V capacitor. I'm using a power MOSFET for this application. I need it to charge instantly as soon as it turns on, or in a few milliseconds. The problem is that to do that I saturate the MOSFET and then turn it off using a 10 V signal to gate source to drive the MOSFET.

It works the first time, as soon as I send the signal it charges, but the problem is that the capacitor gets damaged and all the terminals get shorted. The MOSFET is a [IRFP460](http://www.vishay.com/docs/91237/91237.pdf), it is a 500 V, 20 A and 0.27 ohm MOSFET. I choose it, because it seems to be the correct for this application. I put a 10 A fuse next to the MOSFET to verify if it was being damaged by some inrush current, but it wasn't because as soon as I turned on the MOSFET the fuse didn't pop and the current I measured was not above 5.5 A, and the MOSFET broke down anyway.

The only thing that could be causing the problem is the commutation therefore, the problem must be in gate-source or the driving part. Another thing that called my attention is that if I apply almost 8 V to gate-source the capacitor charges, but only to a half of the voltage with a single pulse of a button, and the MOSFET does not suffer any damage.

The driving signal for the MOSFET will be a pulse that can go from 55 ms to 1 second. So it has to charge the capacitor within these times too. I looked for snubber circuits that can handle this, but the ones I found were parallel to the MOSFET and would get 400 V as soon as the power supply is connected, so I would need components to deal with this and I don't have them. Even if I would get them I don't know if it would work.

This circuit will have another part to discharge the capacitor, but first I need the charge to work. I would like to know if I can implement some kind of snubber for gate-source or what can I do to avoid damaging the MOSFET and switching the voltage needed.

I think the MOSFET could be leaving the safe operating area (SOA) when switching. I also tried to put a diode with a parallel resistor on gate, but no results. How can I do this?

This is my circuit:

[image]

Comment: Did you examine the SOA curve of the FET?

Comment: Please edit your post to fix all the typos. And add a link to the datasheet - there’s no such thing as IRPF460.

Comment: Charging a capacitor like this will result in half of the charging energy being dissipated within the FET. There will be extremely large currents and energy dissipation that will destroy any reasonable size device. You need to either use an appropriate size series resistor that can handle the energy or better approaches use a series inductor and diode to recover that energy and put it back in the capacitor.

Comment: probably the power source has greater ESR than the FET so one must define how one is going to generate 80 Joules of energy in 55 ms at some repetition rate requiring xxkW with better specifications on source and rep rate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sunnyskyguy-ee75](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/426781/fixing-conmutation-for-high-voltage-switching-with-power-mosfet/426786#426786) gives you a really good answer regarding the power problem. Ultimately, I believe you will need to consider the problem you are trying to solve. Either generate a lot of heat by charging the cap quickly with a high current (Warning caps will self heat, Al electrolytic in particular, and can be destroyed by too much current). Or increase the charging time and generate less heat.

**Maybe a non-linear solution is best:**

- Pulse the MOSFET (you'll need a catch diode for the parasitic
  inductance).
- Take this a little further and make a buck DC/DC converter by adding
  one inductor and diode to your circuit. A fixed duty cycle or fixed
  peak current are both simple switch control methods that will charge
  the cap. The high voltage is put across the inductor and not the FET. Bonus is that most power in the inductor goes to charge the cap too rather than being wasted as heat.

**Linear solutions:**

- Power resistor in series with MOSFET to limit the charging current. This is still a trade-off between power in the FET and charging time. The resistor provides another knob to turn so you can balance power and charge time.
- Massive MOSFETs with lots of heat sinking configured as a current source. Feedback circuit to control the current flow by modulating their Vgs. This means a current sense resistor between the FET's source and the negative power terminal. Opamp compares the sense resistor voltage to a reference voltage and drives the MOSFET gate. This can be a difficult circuit to stabilize with a large FET. Step changes on the reference voltage will excite instability.

**Power MOSFETs in brief:**

Most power MOSFETs are designed to act as switches (in switching power converters for example). They can stand off the rated Vds when off. When turned on the NFET pulls its drain down to its source quickly, typically faster than 1 us.

The power MOSFET is designed to be the lowest impedance looking into the node. In your situation the capacitor is the lowest (AC) impedance.

There are MOSFETs called Linear FETs that are intended more for this type of operation. A linear FET has an expanded SOA, a lower gm, and typically a higher Ron than other similar switching power FETs. IXYS (now Littelfuse) has a selection here: [N-Channel Linear Power MOSFETs](https://www.littelfuse.com/products/power-semiconductors/discrete-mosfets/n-channel-linear.aspx).

Comment: These are all very good ideas but Brian needs to give life to this project with real specs on source impedance and max charge dump time. available charger spec link.. One could also slow charge and switch between 2 precharged caps as well. but the problem lacks definition and purpose. Do you agree?

Comment: I totally agree that the number one thing he needs to do is define the problem and solution space. How fast does the cap need to charge? How much cap really needs to be charged? How much current will be pulled out of the cap during discharge into the load.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The mosfet will turn on and charge the capacitor for 55 ms and i would like to charge at least 920 [uf] of it, after that it will turn off and discharge the capacitor in a xeon flashlamp as i said before. I havent design a Duck converter but it seems useful. but i'm working with near 400 V and idk if it can work unless i switch the diode and inductor positions. as i said i've never worked with that.

Comment: You are a bit of a learning curve before you can attempt this design failure question. due to poor design specs, WE call it an XY problem and  Duck hunting hasn't started yet.

Comment: whatdayathink of this solution http://tinyurl.com/y2hqr72w ( not showing ZCS switch ) press reset for ZCS trace

Comment: Cool web simulation. Clearly shows that controlling voltage or current applied to the capacitor is critical. Charging the capacitor from an AC source is much more straight forward than applying 400 VDC. As long as charging is started at the positive zero crossing as you show, it's pretty straight forward. I think moving to AC line as the power source is an excellent way to simplify the problem.

Answer (score 5):

## Analysis

Capacitor specifications are not given, so a typical part,
e.g. 1 mF @600 V ESR=92 [mΩ] @ 10 kHz 20°C, using this capacitor, Kemet ALC70(1)102FP600.

[FET R<sub>dsOn</sub>](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/fairchild/IRFP460.pdf)= 270 mΩ, so out of 270 mΩ + 92 mΩ total, the FET will draw 75% of the power and energy.

The capacitor E<sub>c</sub> = 1/2 CV² = 1/2 * 0.001 F * 400² V = **80 J**, so the capacitor ESR will dissipate 25% of 80 or 20 J while charging up to 80J for a total transfer of 100J . So the **FET must transfer** and dissipate 75% of 100 J or **75 J.**

The worst-case FET safe operating area (SOA) must be observed.

[image]

Yet, the FET can only handle about 900 mJ at 92 µs, but with R<sub>dsON</sub>*C = 270 mΩ * C = 270 µs, the SOA curve points to about 500 mJ vs. a requirement to transfer to dissipate 75 J.

So a much bigger FET is needed with a lower R<sub>dsOn</sub> in the 10 mΩ range, I suspect. I doubt if the supply or capacitor can handle a steady diet of these pulses, so it is back to the drawing board. The term "instantly" needs to be specified and relaxed with a current limiter.

The short circuit current on the capacitor is about 4000 amperes at 400 V.

**["Houston, I think we have a problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Houston,_we_have_a_problem)**

Actual simulation below  (not with an ideal Voltage source the Battery supplies a peak of 441 MW with a 362 ps time constant. ( ideal battery is not possible)

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYmen6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is Houston.  We think we have a solution.
[image]

Comment: This answer is a great overview of the power limitations of discrete MOSFETs.

Comment: I was too casual in the Joules calculations so I repeated in Watts.  FYI @jherbold  you can suggest corrections

Comment: Thank you a lot Sunnyskyguy EE75. What i really need to do is charge the capacitor in 55 ms and then it will discharge the voltaje in a Xenon ionized flashlamp using  an SCR. I dont know how much time will it take to discharge the capacitor once the SCR is turned on. but for the Charging part I understand that im leaving the SOA of the mosfet. so Should i try with a series Inductor and a linear mosfet?  I understand that adding a resistor in series will limit the current but it will affect the charging time as well.

Comment: What is the current limit or ESR of your source and rep. rate for flash.. Now this is a new question. You do realize 100J =1818 Watts *55ms average

Comment: something tells me this will never work. IS this an 80J strobe?

Comment: Im sorry i didn't add this info.. sorry. The power source is just the output of a rectifier bridge it is not filtered with a cap. Im getting 283 V AC at 50 hz rectified so the peak voltage that the cap i want to get charged will get 400 V as peak voltage. Using a dc multimeter i get a value of 256 V DC. I tried to get de ESR of the capacitor but the datasheet doesnt provide it. There are two capacitors connected in series, each one of 2000 uf and 300 V.

Comment: Answering the question. it's a 100 j strobe but it has a cooling system.

Comment: If the cap has no ESR rating then it is not an ultra low ESR type and then is subject to high internal temp rise and destroying the insulation without your awareness as the cap is also a thermal insulator. and you should be using ZCS {Triac or IGBT} bridge and not a diode bridge to reduce the dV/dt with kiloamp ratings

Comment: I just thought of a better solution and added to answer http://tinyurl.com/y2hqr72w for proof of concept.  400V in 5ms at 125A using ZCS

Comment: Thank you so much. I really dont get how the ZCS works in pulsed mode, and what how it interacts with the D flip flop, can you please explain a little bit. Im trying to drive this with a microcontroller so im guessing having an optocoupler instead of the enable switch could work, and also, i will have to take into account the delay that the ZCS and the flip flop generates, or since the charging time is so little should it be discarded.

Comment: yes FF delay is ~ 0.  the quarter sine wave (0 to 90deg) resembles 1/4 of a triangle linear slope except the peak is only 80% of a triangle. Using a rack of PFC film cap with very low ESR, it can easily handle 125²A/ms* ESR = Pd. The ZCS trigger is necessary to start at the zero crossing voltage so I=dV/dt starts from 0V.  E-caps will have memory and higher ESR

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/y345zndf  Press Reset twice to start the slow motion trace then press run-stop anytime or when current flow has stopped. The cursor over trace will show actual result. and turn linked part to turquoise. this is likely to trip most breakers. ! and cause other distrubances

Comment: Thank you again. Im actually using electrolytic capacitors so, how can i deal with that since the ESR will be higher? I could find a the datasheet of the FET just a list with general characteristics. is this an igbt with low  resistance?

Comment: Also, what considerations should i take to desing the ZCS, i've never worked with that using high voltages. or can i buy it? if so, which are the characteristics i should check carefully

Comment: This is custom.  You can buy ZCS pulse IC's but it needs to be stretched to >1/4 to <1/2 cycle with one shot or firmware. I just make with them transistors and keyed AC plugs that always have neutral near 0V with double insulated box.  So gnd is not 0V but offset from diode to DC . But you can use ZCS SSR's at  $ 790 rated for  150 A.  >800V https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/omron-automation-and-safety/G3PH-5150B-DC5-24/Z7536-ND/3461004 but I could design one much cheaper G3PH-5150BL DC5-24

Comment: I really dont have de economic resource. I can try to buy one. Anyway i would like to know how to design one that fits this particular application. How can this be done? Once more Thank you a lot.

Comment: Taking into account that the E-capacitor may have a higher ESR